# Copy Live to a Test site on same domain?

Tags: config, craft2

I have copied my Craft 2.6 live site directory, and created a test directory on our webserver in an effort to create a test site. Also duplicated the db and changed the configure files to point to the new database.

I am having an issue where the following error appears on the test site:
Internal Server Error file_get_contents(http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting .

I disabled all plugins on the test site and enabled them one at a time, and found that the COMPRESSOR 1.0 was causing the issue. If I disable COMPRESSOR 1.0 the error disappears, but the test site doesn't look great.  I noticed also that when I disabled this plugin in the test site admin that it also disabled it on my live site.

Other then the general.php & db.php files in the /config folder is there something else that I need to configure?

Comment: can you check the file and folder permissions and server log as well.

Comment: If the plugin is getting disabled on both sites I would say that almost certainly they are still both using the same database. Also, are you trying to run another instance of craft from a subfolder in the same hosting instance that your live site is running?

Comment: Looks like FileZilla didn't copy my general.php and db.php files. They are now pointing to the test copy so the live site isn't affected when I disable the plugin.  The file_get_contents error appears still though on the test site. I'll look in the logs and permissions.